# Why was a --main-class argument added to jar and jmod instead of using module-info.java to specify it?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I don't understand why the jar and jmod commands use the --main-class argument to "[Specify the] main class to record in the module-info.class file."

A jar file already has this information in the manifest file, so the jar tool could naturally get it from that, but more interesting is why this information isn't specified in module-info.java where it seems to belong in the first place?

(I suppose a similar argument can be made for other jmod arguments like --module-version.)